# ROS installation on Ubuntu taking too long

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, ubuntu-quantal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a ROS as well as Ubuntu newbie. I am trying to install ROS on Ubuntu 12.10 (quantal).Its been more than 6 hrs since I started install Step 1.4 (Desktop-Full Install) described on the Ubuntu installation page on ROS.org. All I see on the Ubuntu terminal is this ....

"Selecting previously unselected package "...insert package name here..."
Unpacking "........"                                                                   (it is doing this selecting and unpacking of various packages one after the other)Seems to be never ending. Is this normal or am I doing some wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64148/ros-installation-on-ubuntu-taking-too-long/) by [ErtahM](https://answers.ros.org/users/5033/ertahm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is the normal outputs.  The length of time is surprising, often that suggests you have issues or hardware that is not powerful enough. What hardware are you running?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ErtahM](https://answers.ros.org/users/5033/ertahm/) on 2013-08-27**:
It was the hardware.... had to get a new computer to be able to work with ROS.
Old system-Dual boot PC, intel T2400 1.83GHz,RAM 2GB, ATI X1300 ...

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-08-27**:
Glad to hear you got it working.  Please accept the answer at the left using the checkmark so others know your question is solved.